# Warn about auto promoted return type in CLion/while compilation

Tags: c++, clion

I recently made a very minor but very hard to find mistake in my code, here's an MCVE:

```
#include<iostream>

int foo(){
    return false;
}

int main(){
    int x = foo();
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, here the function `foo` `return`s `false`, which - as far as I can tell - gets auto-promoted to `int` and stored into `x`.

However, this was a logical mistake on my end, and, surprisingly, was not caught both while compilation and in CLion. `gmm` is my compilation flag. It is supposed to catch memory leaks, runtime errors (mostly all usual undefined behavior) as well as it internally calls `gww` which has the most common warnings enabled.

Moreover, in CLion, CLang-tidy and Clang's own inspector almost always catch all the common mistakes in my code.

I do a lot of competitive programming, and this mistake recently happened live in contest. I would rather want to avoid it. I have attached my compilation flag below. I have all possible C/C++ inspections enabled in CLion Settings. Is it possible to adjust them, add a new setting, or do anything - during either compilation or in CLion or both - to be able to catch this issue at compile time?

---

```
alias gww='g++ -Wall -Weffc++ -pedantic  \
-pedantic-errors -Wextra -Wcast-align \
-Wcast-qual -Wconversion \
-Wdisabled-optimization \
-Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 \
-Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security  \
-Wformat-y2k \
-Wimport  -Winit-self  -Winline \
-Winvalid-pch   \
-Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-format-attribute   \
-Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn \
-Wpacked  -Wpointer-arith \
-Wredundant-decls \
-Wshadow -Wstack-protector \
-Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wswitch-default \
-Wswitch-enum \
-Wunreachable-code -Wunused \
-Wunused-but-set-variable \
-Wunused-parameter \
-Wvariadic-macros \
-Wwrite-strings'
alias gmm="gww -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG"
```

Comment: I don't think you can catch this as according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type `bool` is an integral type.  So `bool` to `int` is just widening.

Comment: Can you show a program that doesn’t work (correctly) as a result of this mistake (whether you meant `return 0;` or `bool foo();` and `bool x=f();`)?  There might be another avenue of attack on the overall issue.

Comment: @DavisHerring The code works if it was intended to return 0. However, in this case, this was not intentional. The intention was to return infinity. This is why I want the IDE/compiler to warn me about such an auto-promotion, as it is probably not intentional.